# Why there is no websocket source available in Spring cloud stream app starters project?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-cloud-stream

There is websocket implementation for Sink but why Source is not available in Spring cloud stream app starters project. Is there any specific reason?

Answer (score 1):

No reason, it's just hasn't been implemented yet. Please feel free to raise [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters). Also, if you feel you can contribute that would help as well.

Comment: Thank you, Issue raised.